# One Active Record per ID

Tags: sql-server-2012, constraints

The address table is shared for both companies and contacts.  I have a constraint that prevents the user from adding a record with both a Company ID and a Contact ID.  I am trying to add another constraint to have only 1 active (ACTIVE FLAG = 'TRUE') address per Company ID or Contact ID.  But I want to be able to have unlimited inactive (ACTIVE FLAG = 'FALSE').

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ADDRESSES]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [chk_ONLY_ONE_ACTIVE_ADDRESS] CHECK  (([COMPANY_ID] IS NOT NULL AND [CONTACT_ID] IS NULL AND [ACTIVE] = 'TRUE' OR [COMPANY_ID] IS NULL AND [CONTACT_ID] IS NOT NULL AND [ACTIVE] = 'TRUE' OR [COMPANY_ID] IS NULL AND [CONTACT_ID] IS NOT NULL AND [ACTIVE] = 'FALSE' OR [COMPANY_ID] IS NOT NULL AND [CONTACT_ID] IS NULL AND [ACTIVE] = 'FALSE'))
GO
```

Where am I missing it?

Thanks
jlimited

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the constraint 'active=true' and 'active=false' for both combinations of contact id and company id so it's a tautology, you may as well remove this constraint. 
I believe the only way to enforce the rule 'only one active flag and 0 to many inactive' is by triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply Jayvee.  Here is the solution that I figured out.

I first created two functions...

One

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCheckForActiveContactAddress](
    @id int
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result INT

    IF @id IS NOT NULL
        SET @result = ISNULL((select count(*) from dbo.Addresses where CONTACT_ID = @ID AND ACTIVE = 'TRUE'),0)
    ELSE
        SET @result = 1

RETURN @result
END
GO
```

Two

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCheckForActiveCompanyAddress](
    @id int
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result INT

    If @id IS NOT NULL
        SET @result = ISNULL((select count(*) from dbo.Addresses where COMPANY_ID = @ID AND ACTIVE = 'TRUE'),0)
    ELSE
        SET @result = 1

RETURN @result
END
GO
```

Then I added the following constraints...

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ADDRESSES]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [chk_COMPANY_OR_CONTACT] CHECK  (([COMPANY_ID] IS NOT NULL AND [CONTACT_ID] IS NULL OR [COMPANY_ID] IS NULL AND [CONTACT_ID] IS NOT NULL))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ADDRESSES]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CHK_ADDRESSES_ONLY_ONE_ACTIVE_CONTACT] CHECK  (([dbo].[fnCheckForActiveContactAddress]([CONTACT_ID])=(1)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ADDRESSES]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CHK_ADDRESSES_ONLY_ONE_ACTIVE_COMPANY] CHECK  (([dbo].[fnCheckForActiveCompanyAddress]([COMPANY_ID])=(1)))
GO
```

This solution seems to work well.

Any thoughts on improving it?

jlimited

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements, this should work (if -1 is not a valid CompanyID or ContactID):

```
create table T (
  CompanyID int,
  ContactID int,
  BothIDs as
    CASE WHEN CompanyID IS NOT NULL and ContactID IS NOT NULL
    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END PERSISTED
  check (BothIDs = 0),
  ActiveFlag varchar(5) check (ActiveFlag in ('TRUE','FALSE')),
  ActiveCheck as
    CASE WHEN ActiveFlag='TRUE' then -1 ELSE COALESCE(CompanyID,ContactID) END,
  unique (ActiveCheck)
);

insert into T values
  (1,NULL,'FALSE'),
  (NULL,2,'FALSE'),
  (3,NULL,'TRUE'),
  (4,NULL,'FALSE');
GO

UPDATE T SET
  ActiveFlag = 'TRUE'
WHERE CompanyID = 4;
```